# What would happen to a person's body if they were struck with a meteorite?

Tags: atmospheric-science, speed, meteors, meteorites

Considering that this is a meteorite that has broken through the Earth's atmosphere, what would happen to one struck by a meteorite? Not a large one of any sort, but one around the size of a fist. How fast are they moving when they land? Has this ever happened to anyone before? Obviously, the effects would be different based on where the meteorite lands on a person. I am simply wondering what would be the differences between a meteorite and that of say, a bullet?

Comment: Meteorites move at 20-30 times the speed of a bullet.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzzle_velocity#References
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoroid

Comment: It is only known to have happened once. It left a bruise and a big legal battle over who owned the meteorite. [For the Only Person Ever Hit by a Meteorite, the Real Trouble Began Later](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/only-person-ever-hit-meteorite-real-trouble-began-later-180961238/)

Answer (score 1):

A meteor travels at 90-180 metres per second, so a baseball sized rock would pretty well kill you dead if it hit anywhere important.  [https://www.amsmeteors.org/fireballs/faqf/#:~:text=At%20that%20point%2C%20called%20the,to%20180%20meters%20per%20second](https://www.amsmeteors.org/fireballs/faqf/#:%7E:text=At%20that%20point%2C%20called%20the,to%20180%20meters%20per%20second)).